# Javascript Code to Append a String Each Character

Tags: javascript, string, append, character

i have this string:

```
"Abcd"
```

i want to append a string `("Z")` each character above:

result:

```
"AZbZcZdZ"
```

please help me, i have searched this in stackoverflow, but no result..

please forgive me about my bad English. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
"Abcd".replace(/./g, "$&Z");
```

Here `/./g` will match all symbols in the given string and `$&` will insert them in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex: 
    "Abcd".replace(/(.)/g, "$1Z");

explanation :

(.): Capture each character in a group.

g: Tell the regex to search the entire string.

$1: is each captured characters.

Answer (score 0):

While replace is one way, you can also use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and concatenate the last Z:

```
"Abcd".split('').join('Z') + 'Z'; // Outputs: AZbZcZdZ
```

As @VizioN mentioned and to my surprise for this short string, [this is also *not* faster than regex](http://jsperf.com/split-join-or-regex).

**UPDATE**: This ***is faster*** than using a regular expression, [even with longer strings](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1557/0/regex-vs-splitjoin). Unsure what the results used to show, but the previous link I provided that supposedly shows that split/join is slower, is actually faster by a considerable percentage.

Comment: Nope, it won't append the last `Z`.

Comment: That is a little trivial. Append Z.

Comment: You need to do: "Abcd".split('').join('Z') + "Z";

Comment: What you say is wrong. Regex will work faster for longer strings and will grasp less memory than you need to work with array.

Comment: @VisioN After looking more into it, you are right! That is my bad. In the end, it's just a slower alternative.